# cant use 2 encoders with the a21.hpp library

Tags: c++, arduino, encoder

I am trying to build an etch a sketch with and oled display and 2 encoders but only one encoder is being read. The y isn't being updated and I have checked that the encoders and wires work by switching the wires.

Here is the code:

```
#include <U8g2lib.h> //for display
#include <a21.hpp> //for rotary encoder

#define OLED_SDA 4                                                            //
#define OLED_SCL 5                                                            //          OLED
U8G2_SSD1306_128X64_NONAME_F_HW_I2C u8g2(U8G2_R0);                            //


using namespace a21;
EC11 encoder1;
EC11 encoder2;

const byte encoder1PinA = 2;                    //    encoder 1
const byte encoder1PinB = 3;                    //

const byte encoder2PinA = 4;                    //    encoder 2
const byte encoder2PinB = 5;                    //

int cursorX = 1;
int cursorY = 1;

void setup() {
  u8g2.begin();
  u8g2.clearBuffer();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  pinMode(encoder1PinA, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(encoder1PinB, INPUT_PULLUP);

  pinMode(encoder2PinA, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(encoder2PinB, INPUT_PULLUP);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(encoder1PinA), pinDidChange1, CHANGE);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(encoder1PinB), pinDidChange1, CHANGE);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(encoder2PinA), pinDidChange2, CHANGE);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(encoder2PinB), pinDidChange2, CHANGE);
}

void loop() { 
  CheckEncoder();
  Serial.println("Y= " + String(cursorY));
  Serial.println("X= " + String(cursorX));
  Serial.println();
}

void SendDisplayBuffer() {
  u8g2.setFont(u8g2_font_courR18_tf); // Choose a font
  u8g2.setFontMode(1); // Set font mode to transparent
  u8g2.setCursor(cursorX, cursorY);
  u8g2.drawPixel(cursorX, cursorY);
  u8g2.sendBuffer();
}

void CheckEncoder() {
  EC11Event encoderE1;
  EC11Event encoderE2;
  
  if (encoder1.read(&encoderE1)) {
    if (encoderE1.type == EC11Event::StepCW) {
      // Clockwise rotation
      cursorX += encoderE1.count; // Adjust the cursor's X position
    } else {
      // Counterclockwise rotation
      cursorX -= encoderE1.count; // Adjust the cursor's X position
    }

    SendDisplayBuffer();
  }

  if (encoder2.read(&encoderE2)) {
    if (encoderE2.type == EC11Event::StepCW) {
      // Clockwise rotation
      cursorY -= encoderE2.count; // Adjust the cursor's Y position
    } else {
      // Counterclockwise rotation
      cursorY += encoderE2.count; // Adjust the cursor's Y position
    }

    SendDisplayBuffer();
  }
}

void pinDidChange1() {
  encoder1.checkPins(digitalRead(encoder1PinA), digitalRead(encoder1PinB));
}

void pinDidChange2() {
  encoder2.checkPins(digitalRead(encoder2PinA), digitalRead(encoder2PinB));
}
```

I have tried a lot of things and i realize that there is an issue in the CheckEncoder() function. other libraries dont work for some reason with my arduino uno r3 and the ec11 encoder.